# WSDL runtime validation with JAX-WS

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

We are developing an MDA platform that has support for Web Services. The user can provide a WSDL in runtime and we generate all the artifacts (service interface and implementation for the server, and consumer for the client) using JAX-WS internally.

We want to add validation on the WSDL document provided by the user. Right now the user has to validate that with an external tool like Oxygen, XMLSpy or a web tool, but we want to add that as a part of our system. A nice-to-have feature would be schema validation aswell, including the embedded schemas of the WSDLs.

In JAX-WS (RI) there is support for schema validation in runtime (using the @SchemaValidation annotation) but we haven't found any support for WSDL validation.

We've tried to integrate [Eclipse's WSDL validator](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_WSDL_Validator_Outside_of_Eclipse) but it doesn't seem to work for us.

Is there any way of doing this with JAX-WS? 
If not, is there any other validation framework that we can integrate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion in your question that I need to clarify first.

You seem to want the ability to validate the WSDL (syntax + WS-I) and XSDs, either embedded or referenced externally by the WSDL. On the other hand you bring in @SchemaValidation, which is actually used to validate instance documents.

In a traditional development approach, one might say you want at least the ability to validate design-time artifacts (WSDL+XSDs).

For this scenario then, I would recommend the following:

WSDL: for WS-I compliance testing, please take a look at the [test tools section of the WS-I site](http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=testingtools). It is not clear how the licensing they have with their test tooling would work with yours, but at least it should give you an idea for what to look if it doesn't work for you.

UPDATE: Additional WSDL validation resources:
- [Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_WSDL_Validator_Outside_of_Eclipse) based, how to use outside Eclipse.

XSDs: if you really need separate validation for XSD files, things may get tricky for a production quality product; [WSDL4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/) is not much help here, and I believe [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/) is the way to go for this kind of job. You have to extract content from the types section as one or more XSD files (could be more than one XSD file, take a look at some examples, Microsoft's SharePoint WSDLs come to my mind as a good test case), assign a base uri for each extracted XSD that matches the WSDLs location, then use XSOM to validate those.

Since you're generating the client, you're most likely not concerned with validating, say of the HTTP headers (SOAP 1.1/HTTP, SOAPAction, if it matches the WSDL operation definition). If you end up developing an interest in that as well, which I call runtime validation, then I would recommend a different layout in your approach (i.e. I would not rely on @SchemaValidation  but rather do it through a transparent, and generic, proxy service).

Comment: I mentioned the @SchemaValidation just to avoid confusion between instance and schema/wsdl validation. I was asking, as you said, about the validation of the design-time artifacts.
About the WS-I site, I had a look to the tools and that might work but I'm not sure about the licensing.
About the XSDs, we are already separating those from the WSDL and we support multiple embedded schemas. I will investigate how to validate those with XSOM.
And about your last point, we generate servers aswell, and validating those headers might be interesting.
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: For some reason, and after a quick look at the license file, it seems to me that WS-I tool stack is not friendly towards closed, or commercial tooling. I wanted to point that out to make sure you also look at these aspects. For validating headers, I've seen cases where the client sends the correct Soap body without the correct SOAPAction.  Also, thank you for clarifying, I thought so about @SchemaValidation.

Comment: Yes, you are right: http://netzooid.com/blog/2006/11/26/is-ws-i-open-look-at-their-test-license/
I think that we will have to find other solution or framework.
About validating the XSDs, I've tried with XSOMParser creating an ErrorHandler and it works fine.
I think that I should leave this question opened as the main concern was WSDL validation, but anyway thanks a lot for your responses.

Comment: Please see updated, Eclipse seems to have a validator that could be used outside Eclipse; however, the WS-I part is rather not there...

Comment: Hi, as I said in my first post, we tried to use Eclipse's validator but we didn't succeed. I will try again and update this post with my results.